# Grant permission to trigger from owner account

Tags: oracle, database-administration, privileges

I have a trigger STUDENT_DATA_UPDATE in my two oracle accounts. One is owner account and another is user account. Below are the details.

Owner account which has all the privileges:

```
<connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@eu.national.com:15001/STUD</connection-url>
<driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
<user-name>NATIONAL_OWN</user-name>
<password>********</password>
```

USER account which has no privileges:

```
<connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@eu.national.com:15001/STUD</connection-url>
<driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
<user-name>NATIONAL_USR</user-name>
<password>********</password>
```

I am able to change ,Disable or enable the trigger from OWNER account which has permissions. But i am not able to do any changes to the trigger from USER account. My question here is, I want to grant the permission to change the trigger from NATIONAL_OWN to NATIONAL_USR account which can disable and enable the same trigger in it.

Comment: You would need powerful `ANY` privileges to be granted to the user. Or to have a wrapper procedure in the owner schema that does the modifications, but that's probably only really feasible for enable/disable. Why would you want anyone except the owner to change the trigger though?

Comment: Actually we are using NATIONAL_USR user in ET and Prod environment. We got a requirement where I need to disable the trigger only to a particular functionality and then enable it once the functionality gets executed. So we don't have permissions to do that with the existing user. We need to grant permission to alter the trigger. I don't think that would be correct option to give ANY privilege to the user. Can you please explain me how to do the wrapper procedure that enable/disable the trigger for a particular table.

Comment: The wrapper procedure is a procedure owned by the owner of the trigger.  It executes with the permissions of the owner.  Then you grant EXECUTE on the procedure to whoever needs to execute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user can only enable or disable another user's trigger if they are granted the powerful `alter any trigger` privilege, which is probably overkill and dangerous. You could restrict it with a DDL trigger but that just gets more complicated.

You could create wrapper procedures, possibly in a package, e.g. in the `NATIONAL_OWN` schema:

```
create package trigger_pkg as
  procedure disable_trigger;
  procedure enable_trigger;
end trigger_pkg;
/

create package body trigger_pkg as
  procedure disable_trigger is
  begin
    execute immediate 'alter trigger STUDENT_DATA_UPDATE disable';
  end disable_trigger;

  procedure enable_trigger is
  begin
    execute immediate 'alter trigger STUDENT_DATA_UPDATE enable';
  end enable_trigger;
end trigger_pkg;
/

grant execute on trigger_pkg to NATIONAL_USR;
```

Then as `NATIONAL_USR` you can do:

```
begin
    NATIONAL_OWN.trigger_pkg.disable_trigger;
end;
/
```

and

```
begin
    NATIONAL_OWN.trigger_pkg.enable_trigger;
end;
/
```

You could have one procedure with an enable/disable flag instead of you prefer.

> Is there a way where i could actually call these procedures disable_trigger and enable_trigger from a java code.

You can use a CallableStatement, either with the anonymous block syntax:

```
stmt = conn.prepareCall("begin NATIONAL_OWN.trigger_pkg.disable_trigger; end;");
stmt.execute();
```

or the ANSI syntax:

```
stmt = conn.prepareCall("{ call NATIONAL_OWN.trigger_pkg.disable_trigger }");
stmt.execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I need to disable and enable trigger for only one particular functionality in my java code. Is there a way where i could actually call these procedures disable_trigger and enable_trigger from a java code.

Comment: Of course, just use a CallableStatement for the anonymous block (without the `/`).

Comment: Thank you Alex for the solution. I will try it out and let you know here.